# How to add button under text

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter so here is my code where its printing one centre text but I need a button under the text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() 
{
  runApp(MaterialApp(
     title: 'Hello Flutter',
     home: HomeWidget(),

  ));
}


class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget 
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) 
    {
      return Material(
         child: Container(child: Center(child: Text('Hello World Of Flutter Development'),),),       
         // Need Button Here beneath Text   
      );

      } //Widget
} //End of Class
```

Comment: Under or beneath? There is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use - `Column` Widget.

Learn more about [drawing Layouts](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Hello Flutter',
    home: HomeWidget(),
  ));
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('Hello World Of Flutter Development'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text('Button'),) // Button under Text
      ]),

    );
  } //Widget
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Column Widget

```
 Column(
      children: [
        Text('Hello World Of Flutter Development'),
FlatButton(onPressed:() {}, child:Text('name on button')),           
     ],
    )
```